Displaying live camera feed in Qt
I am doing camera calibration through Qt. I have several windows for it, such as exposure, blur, distortion and so on. I want to show the live camera feed in the labels present in each of the windows.
For testing purpose, I have created a glob and stored several demo images in a vector. Then, I am running a while loop and emitting a signal with the current image, inside a thread. The other thread is used to initialize the UI. Then, this signal is connected to the slots of the individual window to set the images in their label. But this approach crashes the application for windows which perform costly operations on the image. Is there any other approach to address this issue?
Mainwindow.cpp:
std::string folder = "/path/of/images/*.jpg";
    cv::glob(folder,images);

void MainWindow::liveIMG::setReference(MainWindow *m) 
{
    this->m = m;
}

void MainWindow::liveIMG::run() 
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if(i == m->images.size()) i = 0;
        m->img = cv::imread(m->images[i]);
        i++;
        QImage image(m->img.data, m->img.cols, m->img.rows, m->img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        emit updateImage(image);
    }
}    

connect(this, &MainWindow::updateImageMainWindow, exposure, &Exposure::setInitialFeed);

Exposure.cpp:
void Exposure::setInitialFeed(const QImage &img)
{
    Mat test = cv::Mat(img.height(), img.width(), CV_8UC3, const_cast<uchar*>(img.bits()), img.bytesPerLine());
    srcImg = test;
    QImage image(srcImg.data, srcImg.cols, srcImg.rows, srcImg.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    ui->lblCameraFeed->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}

Note: I am passing a QImage in the signal since cv::Mat images won't be compatible in signal-slot mechanism.

The QImage constructor you're using requires the data pointed to by the first parameter to remain valid throughout the lifetime of the object.  I don't think that requirement is satisfied in the code shown.
